# Row to column transformation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below

```
+----+------+------+-----+-----+
| id | year | sell | buy | own |
+----+------+------+-----+-----+
| 1  | 2016 | 9    | 2   | 10  |
| 1  | 2017 | 9    | 0   | 10  |
| 1  | 2018 | 0    | 2   | 10  |
| 2  | 2016 | 7    | 2   | 11  |
| 2  | 2017 | 2    | 0   |  0  |
| 2  | 2018 | 0    | 0   | 18  |
+----+------+------+-----+-----+
```

I'm trying to transpose rows to columns but instead of aggregate the values, i wanted to keep some letters if it is not `0`(S-Sell,B-Buy,O-Own). If there are values for all columns for particular year then i need S_B_O for that year. If there are values only for sell and buy then S_B etc., so Expected output is

```
+----+-------+------+------+
| ID | 2016  | 2017 | 2018 |
+----+-------+------+------+
| 1  | S_B_O | S_O  | B_O  |
+----+-------+------+------+
| 2  | S_B_O | S    | O    |
+----+-------+------+------+
```

I'm new to python and have no idea how we can do this. I know only the basic pivot for aggregation as shown below. is it possible? any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_excel('Pivot.xlsx')

pivot = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["ID"],columns='year',values ='sell' ,aggfunc = np.sum,fill_value=0)
```

Dataframe

```
id,year,sell,buy,own
1,2016,9,2,10
1,2017,9,0,10
1,2018,0,2,10
2,2016,7,2,11
2,2017,2,0,0
2,2018,0,0,18
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `df.dot` with `df.pivot` here:

```
u = df[['sell','buy','own']]
(df.assign(v=u.ne(0).dot(u.columns.str[0].str.upper()+'_').str[:-1])
.pivot("id","year","v"))
```

---

```
year   2016 2017 2018
id                   
1     S_B_O  S_O  B_O
2     S_B_O    S    O
```

With full formatting;

```
u = df[['sell','buy','own']]
out = (df.assign(v=u.ne(0).dot(u.columns.str[0].str.upper()+'_').str[:-1])
      .pivot("id","year","v").rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index())
print(out)
```

---

```
   id   2016 2017 2018
0   1  S_B_O  S_O  B_O
1   2  S_B_O    S    O
```

Comment: Excellent. I never thought it will be as simple as this. In SQL i'm doing the same with big set of code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

- Cast `'sell'`, `'buy'`, and `'own'` as Boolean (`df.iloc[:, -3:].astype(bool)`), multiply the Boolean by the characters `['S', 'B', 'O']`, and `join` them as a combined string.

  - `0` evaluates as `False`, and the other numbers are `True`
  - `df.iloc[:, -3:]` is equivalent to `df[['sell', 'buy', 'own']]`, for this dataframe.
- The list comprehension removes empty values, otherwise the results would include extra `_` (e.g. `_S_O` or `__S`).
- Since this solution uses, `.apply`, it will be slower than the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64228717/7758804) by [anky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9840637/anky)
- I thought `.astype(bool) * ['S', 'B', 'O']` was a neat trick, worth sharing.

```py
import pandas as pd

# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'year': [2016, 2017, 2018, 2016, 2017, 2018], 'sell': [9, 9, 0, 7, 2, 0], 'buy': [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0], 'own': [10, 10, 10, 11, 0, 18]})

# Cast sell, buy, own as Bool, multiple and combine as string
df['str'] = (df.iloc[:, -3:].astype(bool) * ['S', 'B', 'O']).apply(lambda x: '_'.join([v for v in x if v]), axis=1)

# display(df)
   id  year  sell  buy  own    str
0   1  2016     9    2   10  S_B_O
1   1  2017     9    0   10    S_O
2   1  2018     0    2   10    B_O
3   2  2016     7    2   11  S_B_O
4   2  2017     2    0    0      S

# pivot
dfp = df.pivot(index='id', columns='year', values='str')

# display(dfp)
year   2016 2017 2018
id                   
1     S_B_O  S_O  B_O
2     S_B_O    S    O
```

### Running in Idle

[image]

Comment: Yes. You are right. After upgrade, it is working as expected. Thanks a ton :) and sorry for disturbing u at this point of time. Good Night :)

Comment: @Avinash Good Night, going to bed for real now. Glad you got it working. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

that's my favourite pandas operation (unstack) :-)
You can do it as follows. Most of the work is to build the strings as you requested:

```
df['operation']= df['sell'].map(lambda v: ['S'] if v != 0 else [])
indexer= df['buy'] != 0
df.loc[indexer, 'operation'].map(lambda v: v.append('B'))
indexer= df['own'] != 0
df.loc[indexer, 'operation'].map(lambda v: v.append('O'))
df['operation']= df['operation'].map(lambda l: '_'.join(l))
df.set_index(['id', 'year'], inplace=True)
df_res= df['operation'].unstack()
df_res
```

With the test data like:

```
from io import StringIO
infile= StringIO(
""" id | year | sell | buy | own 
 1  | 2016 | 9    | 2   | 10  
 1  | 2017 | 9    | 0   | 10  
 1  | 2018 | 0    | 2   | 10  
 2  | 2016 | 7    | 2   | 11  
 2  | 2017 | 2    | 0   |  0  
 2  | 2018 | 0    | 0   | 18""")
df= pd.read_csv(infile, sep='|', dtype='int16') #.set_index('Date')
df.head()
df.columns= [col.strip() for col in df.columns]
```

you get the result:

```
year   2016 2017 2018
id                   
1     S_B_O  S_O  B_O
2     S_B_O    S    O
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Works as well